# How we can make this circle background color disappearing animation CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, frontend

Can any give me any idea or any links to implement this kind of background color disappearing animation

[image]

[image]

Comment: SVG images are fun to animate with tools like GSAP. Google it! ;)

Comment: What images are you trying to animate and what code have you got already?

Comment: Not implemented, my task is to implement a circle with CSS having a border as white color and background color as white, which on turns background color into transparent on animation in circular way as like clock. attached images for idea

Answer (score 1):

not exactly but you can do that with svg something like this.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: #222;
}

.cntr {
  margin: auto;
}

.btn-radio {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.btn-radio:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .btn-radio {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .btn-radio:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
}
.btn-radio svg {
  fill: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn-radio svg circle {
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #C8CCD4;
}
.btn-radio svg path {
  stroke: #008FFF;
}
.btn-radio svg path.inner {
  stroke-width: 6;
  stroke-dasharray: 19;
  stroke-dashoffset: 19;
}
.btn-radio svg path.outer {
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-dasharray: 57;
  stroke-dashoffset: 57;
}
.btn-radio input {
  display: none;
}
.btn-radio input:checked + svg path {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.btn-radio input:checked + svg path.inner {
  stroke-dashoffset: 38;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.btn-radio input:checked + svg path.outer {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
.btn-radio span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="cntr">
    <label for="rdo-1" class="btn-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="rdo-1" name="radio-grp">
      <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="9"></circle>
        <path d="M10,7 C8.34314575,7 7,8.34314575 7,10 C7,11.6568542 8.34314575,13 10,13 C11.6568542,13 13,11.6568542 13,10 C13,8.34314575 11.6568542,7 10,7 Z" class="inner"></path>
        <path d="M10,1 L10,1 L10,1 C14.9705627,1 19,5.02943725 19,10 L19,10 L19,10 C19,14.9705627 14.9705627,19 10,19 L10,19 L10,19 C5.02943725,19 1,14.9705627 1,10 L1,10 L1,10 C1,5.02943725 5.02943725,1 10,1 L10,1 Z" class="outer"></path>
      </svg>
    </label>
  </div>
```